# How can I define a single-column array in Excel using a starting cell and a variable length?

Tags: excel

For example, lets say I want to use the COUNT formula from cell A1, to cell A[X].

> =COUNT(A1:A[X])

How can I write the syntax of the array so that the value of "X" is dynamically generated based on the input from another formula that is nested inside that COUNT formula?

Comment: You have to use `INDIRECT()` or `OFFSET()` or `INDEX()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX()` function with `COUNTA()`. Try-

```
=A1:INDEX(A1:A50000,COUNTA(A1:A50000))
```

Then use `COUNT()` function. Or using `OFFSET()` function.

```
=COUNT(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A1:A50000)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The offset function is what I needed!